# How do I reset a user password from the console in Hobo/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

The rails framework Hobo is brilliant and automatically creates the first user as the admin user (unless you ask it not to).  The problem I have is that running rails in development I can't remember what the password was.  This should be trivial because I just run `rails console`, find the user `admin = User.find :first` and reset the password (trying)

```
 admin.password = 'Anything1234'
 admin.password_confirmation = admin.password
 admin.save
 >false
 admin.errors
 >{:current_password=>["is not correct"]}
```

I.e. the implication is that the variable current_password needs to be set correctly before I can change the existing password.

I'm afraid the Hobo documentation doesn't help in this case.  Does anyone know the how to drive the Hobo user model to reset the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 possible solutions:

1:  run your app, and click on the forgot password link.   The message will appear in your logs, so you don't need a mailer set up.

2:  Just save without doing any validations:

```
admin.save(false)
```

EDIT: in Rails 3 this is

```
admin.save(:validate => false)
```

3: Another option is just to delete all users so you get your initial user entry screen back.

4: If you really want to run the validations, you can trigger the request_password_reset lifecycle:

```
admin.lifecycle.request_password_reset!(Guest.new)
```

then look in development log for the reset password key

```
u.lifecycle.reset_password!(Guest.new, :key => 'a0a2db1035065fa7ad5d46d35669d206aee73668', :password=>"test123", :password_confirmation=>"test123")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried 1 - but the link didn't work for other reasons.  Saving without validation is the obvious one that I missed!  3 is what I went for without anything better, 4 is great to have a proper view of how it works.

Comment: Quite frankly #3 is my most common choice for problems of this sort.  Most of my projects have a script to build up an initial database so I drop & rebuild the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set the `current_password` before you set the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields. This is to stop the user from changing the password without originally knowing the password.

Therefore, you would need to do something like this:

```
admin.current_password = 'password'
admin.password = 'Anything1234'
admin.password_confirmation = admin.password
admin.save
```

Comment: Ryan, I think that was rather my point - that if you do not know the current password you cannot save a new one.  The question is what then?